# Limiting the amount of text parsed with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to limit the amount text I split from the inputted text, in order to set a label in my program. My problem is that my regex will grab letters from places I don't want it to.

The text is taken from a textArea inside my program which is then used in the setTuningLabel Method.

```
    public void convertButtonClick(ActionEvent e) {
        setTuningLabel(tabArea.getText());
    }
```

```
    public void setTuningLabel(String tuning) { 
        // this is the current method I have for setting the label
        String a = "";
        for (String c : tuning.split("([^a-gA-G#♭]+#?)")) {
            a += c + ", ";
            labelTuning.setText("Tuning: " + a.toUpperCase());
            System.out.println(c);
            
        }
    }
```

The typical input into this method would look something like this:

```
 
[Verse]
e |-------------------------------------------|
C#|-------------------------------------------|
A |-------------------------------------------|
E |-------------------------------------------|
A |---7----7----10----7----5----3----2--------| (x8)
E |-------------------------------------------|
  // I want it to cut off here
[Pre-chorus]
e |---------------------------------------------|
C#|------------------------0-0-0-0--0-0-0-0-----|
A |------------------------0-0-0-0--0-0-0-0-----|
E |-0-0--------------------0-0-0-0--0-0-0-0-----|
A |-0-0--5-5-5-5--5-5-5-5--0-0-0-0--0-0-0-0-----|
E |-0-0--3-3-3-3--3-3-3-3--0-0-0-0--0-0-0-0-----|
```

From this input I want to grab the letters at the beginning of each line, until it his the newline which then I would like it to stop. So it should grab e, C#, A, E, A, E. The number of lines here can vary it will not always be 6.

With the current regex I have it will not ignore the letters inside the brackets, which I want it to do, I also want it to stop at the first break in the input. This is typically a new line.

With the current way it functions the label would be currently set to
*E, E, E, C#, A, E, A, E, E, C, E, C#, A, E, A, E.* Here its grabbing letters from inside the Square brackets and continuing  longer than I would like it to.

What I want the output to look like would be
*E, C#, A, E, A, E.*

Comment: It's better to specify the exact input and the expected output. You should add these two things at the end of the content your question currently has.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash There isn't a straight forward exact input due to the nature of the program. If you mean for the problem I'm describing the input mentioned is what is used to get the output.

Comment: You might want to improve your question a bit. It seems to me that all you want is to grab the the row identifiers along the left side of your table and ignore everything else. If that's correct, there are a lot easier ways to do what you want, but I suspect there's more to it.

Comment: @MarsAtomic That is all I want to do, this was the only way I thought about approaching the problem which clearly isn't the best way to do so. That row can very in length. In this case it's 6 but in other cases it could be 4, 8 etc. But I just want the grab the first set of them if that makes sense?

Comment: Have you tried to put the ^ in front of the [ ? Then it only matches Strings at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Restated simply, you're looking to grab the first one or two characters of a String. I'm assuming you know how to iterate through a file line by line  (let me know if this is not the case), so we'll just assume you've read a line from your file and put it into a String variable called `line`.

```
String note = line.substring(0,2).trim();
```

The substring method takes the characters at index 0 and 1 from `line`. Notes may not be followed by sharp or flat notation. In those cases, grabbing two characters will give us an unwanted space following the note, so the `trim()` method is used to remove that whitespace.

You can then concatenate these notes. Pardon the mix of p code and actual code -- I'm lazy.

```
while(my file has lines)
{
    String notes = "";
    String note = line.substring(0,2).trim();
    notes = notes + ", " + note;
}
```

How to read the context of a text area line by line (this is technically a separate question and should be posted as such, but in for a penny, in for a pound...)

```
String myText = tabArea.getText();
String note = "";
String notes = "";
String[] lines = myText.split("-|");
for(int counter = 0; counter < lines.length - 1; counter++)
{
    note = line.substring(0,2).trim();
    notes = notes + ", " + note;
}

notes = notes + note; // this appends the final note without the comma and space
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, however I should of stated (my bad, I'm new to stackOverflow) that the input is pasted into a text area. which is then loaded into this method. It's not loaded from a file. Ill add the code to the main post